# Python openAL 3D sound

Tags: python, audio, 3d, openal

I just started with python and I am making program for audio manipulation.
I am trying to implement 3D sound with openAL in my python application, but I just can get it to work

this is my code for 3D sound:

```
from openal.loaders import load_wav_file
from openal.audio import *

sink = SoundSink()   
listener = SoundListener()
SoundSink.activate(sink)
listener.position = (0, 0, 0)
listener.velocity = (0, 0, 0)
listener.orientation = (0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0)
source = SoundSource()
wavsound = load_wav_file("test.wav")
source.queue(wavsound)
#SoundSink.play(source)
sink.play(source)
```

The code executes, but it doesn't play the sound

Comment: Just a thought; have you tried putting a delay at the end of the program, before it quits? OpenAL intrinsically operates in the background, but if the program closes then AL will usually shut down with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer:**

I mentioned in the comments below that PyAL had not been updated for a while. Indeed, while the bitbucket repo I linked to no longer exists, this is not accurate. The [PyPI page for PyAL](https://pypi.org/project/python-openal/) is last dated at 12/25/2019, with [the repo](https://github.com/NicklasTegner/PyAL) dated at 9/11/2020 as of the time of this update. In contrast, the [PyPI page for PyOpenAL](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenAL/) is last dated at 12/17/2019, with [the repo](https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyOpenAL) also dated at 12/17/2019. I have kept the old answer below, and am adding the code to support PyOpenAL as requested by @Caridorc above it.

In order to get PyOpenAL to work, I needed to manually add an `openal.dll` file to the installed library so that dependency could be found by [its internal library loader utility](https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyOpenAL/blob/master/openal/library_loader.py). I also needed to avoid setting the position tuples for my `Listener` and `Source` classes directly and had to use `set_position` method calls instead so that the position changes would be propagated to the underlying C library (*ideally `PyOpenAL` should be modified to use @property syntax to seamlessly handle this*).

The wave sound file used in both demos is [here](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/%7Ei101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand60.wav). Note that **only mono, NOT STEREO, sound files are supported**.

Here is the updated code:

```
import time
from openal import * 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_pos = 5
    sleep_time = 5
    source = oalOpen("CantinaBand60.wav")
    source.set_position([x_pos, 0, 0])
    source.set_looping(True)
    source.play()
    listener = Listener()
    listener.set_position([0, 0, 0])

    while True:
        source.set_position([x_pos, 0, 0])
        print("Playing at: {0}".format(source.position))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        x_pos *= -1
    
    oalQuit()
```

---

**Old Answer using PyAL:**

It turns out that there are some examples of how to use PyAL at the Bitbucket repository page [here](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-al/src/bd5ae7f4b283177d6ec638000e3e246d8e572ca7/examples/?at=default). Based off the `audioplayer.py` example, I made this annoying-sounding example with the sound alternative between the left and right headphone speaker according to a sine wave:

```
import time
import math
from openal.audio import SoundSink, SoundSource
from openal.loaders import load_wav_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sink = SoundSink()
    sink.activate()
    source = SoundSource(position=[0, 0, 0])
    source.looping = True
    data = load_wav_file("CantinaBand60.wav")
    source.queue(data)
    sink.play(source)
    t = 0
    while True:
        x_pos = 5*math.sin(math.radians(t))
        source.position = [x_pos, source.position[1], source.position[2]]
        sink.update()
        print("playing at %r" % source.position)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        t += 5
```

Comment: Regarding your `from` imports, openal.audio causes me an error, such that the module doesn't exist? I installed `PyOpenAL` with pip, is this correct? Is this answer out of date for the current version or have I got something wrong?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 Yes, the code here looks deprecated now. It relies on PyAL rather than the PyOpenAL wrapper. The former has not been updated since 2013 it looks like. The PyPi page for PyOpenAL has a reference section though that should make this code trivial to port over.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon I have put a bounty on this question, if you would like to update the code the new version of the library.

Comment: @Caridorc I have added the updated/translated code to support PyOpenAL. The biggest gotchas were with installation (needed to point the library to the dll for the openal c library) and correctly setting the position of the source and listener. Hope this helps!

Comment: hey, thanks a lot, the code runs for me, could you please add a link to the wav file used to make the example more self-contained also for the benefit of future visitors?

Comment: Also please add a disclaimer saying that this only works for mono audio files and not for stereo ones.

Comment: I used this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/129-CPosHPoeH4iKlCYyH6GNZLQITMudp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also I think with x_pos = - x_pos and a longer sleep time it is easier to check if code is working or not

Comment: ok will make those updates in the next day or two, thanks for the valid feedback