# OpenAL Python openal.audio module not found

Tags: python, openal

I was trying to do some work in Python with simulating 3D sound. I was trying to run this code (provided in the answer): [Python openAL 3D sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555867/python-openal-3d-sound) and similar, both times receiving:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openal.audio'
```

I've installed OpenAL, PyAL, and tried installing an older version (uninstalled it and reinstalled the new one), but it still doesn't work.

I've also tried the following code:

```py
from openal import *

class AudioSource:
    def __init__(self, path_to_file):
        self.src = oalOpen(path_to_file)

    def play(self):
        self.src.play()
        self.src.position = (-100, 0, 0)
        self.src.update()
```

which doesn't use the openal.audio package, but the position doesn't seem to have any effect on the sound source either. I'm open to any solution (including using a newer package if one is available that will produce 3D sound)

Answer (score 1):

Using link to python OpenAL library at https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-al/downloads/

just download either the tar.gz or other one then once expanded it gives you dir something like

```
~/src/PyAL-0.1.0/
```

then type

```
make
```

if no errors there to install issue

```
make install

sudo make install  #  this works on ubuntu ... dunno about Windows or osx
```

then to kick tires run the provided example

```
cd ~/src/PyAL-0.1.0/examples/
python ./player.py
```

which is a rather nice 3D audio demo ... now your python import openal will work ... I confirmed this by running another script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945609/147175

If this still goes pear shaped what OS are you on ?